# When was a RSA Private Key Introduced?

Tags: rsa, keys, history

I'm doing some research into the RSA cryptosystem but I just need some clarity on how it worked when it was published in the 70s. Now I know that it works with public keys but did it also work with private keys back then or did it use a shared public key first and then private keys were introduced later?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Maybe you should read this first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: RSA has always used both private keys (for decryption) and public keys (for encryption).

Comment: "... need some clarity on how it worked when it was published in the 70s" How about reading the actual publication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RSA never was intended as a symmetric/secret key cryptosystem, or extensively used as such. Public/Private key pairs have been used for RSA from day one.

A very close cousin of RSA, also using Public/Private key pairs, was known (but not published) at the [GCHQ](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/topics/our-history) significantly before RSA was published. See Clifford Cocks's declassified [*A Note on 'Non-secret Encryption'*](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/sites/default/files/document_files/Cliff%20Cocks%20paper%2019731120.pdf) (1973). Public-key cryptography was theorized at the GCHQ even before, see James Ellis's declassified [*The Possibility of Secure Non-Secret Encryption*](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/sites/default/files/document_files/CESG_Research_Report_No_3006_0.pdf) (1969), and his account in the declassified [*The history of Non-Secret Encryption*](http://fgrieu.free.fr/histnse/ellisdox.pdf) (1987). See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20362/555) for more references on these early works.

---

As kindly reminded by poncho: the Pohlig-Hellman exponentiation cipher is a symmetric analog of textbook RSA. It uses as public parameters a large public prime $p$ with $(p-1)/2$ also prime, and two random odd secret exponents $e$ and $d$ with the relation $e\cdot d\equiv1\pmod{(p-1)}$; encryption of $m$ with $1<m<p$ is $c\gets m^e\bmod p$, decryption is $m\gets c^e\bmod p$. By incorporating the computation of $d$ from the encryption key $e$ into the decryption, and using [cycle walking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_cycle_walking) to coerce down the message space to bitstrings and remove a few fixed points, it becomes a full-blown block cipher by the modern definition of that. Security is related to the discrete logarithm problem in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ . An algorithm for solving that is the main subject of the article, and what [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) now designates. The encryption algorithm has little practical interest, because it is very slow for a symmetric-only algorithm. It never caught in practice, and I believe never was intended to do so.

I found no earlier reference than: Stephen C. Pohlig and Martin E. Hellman, [*An Improved Algorithm for Computing Logarithm over $GF(p)$ and Its Cryptographic Significance*](https://www-ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/28.pdf) published [in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1978.1055817), Volume 24 Issue 1, January 1978.

RSA was clearly known to the authors when they submitted this correspondence. They make explicit reference to:

1. Ronald L. Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman, [*On Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems*](http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA039036), Technical Memo MIT/LCS/TM-82, dated April 1977 (received by the Defense Documentation Center on May 3, 1977; publication date unknown).
2. Ronald L. Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman, [*A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems*](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf) published [in Communications of the ACM](https://doi.org/10.1145/359340.359342), Volume 21 Issue 2, February 1978 (received April 4, 1977; revised September 1, 1977).

Note: I discovered (1.) only because it is referenced by Pohlig and Hellman; it has a number of rough edges fixed in (2.), including a byzantine and unnecessary complication in the handling of messages not coprime with the public modulus, that are telling of the novelty.

I refer to poncho's [account](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52525/555#comment116158_52528) on chronology.

Comment: "Modular exponentation was proposed after RSA as a building block for symmetric cryptography"; actually, according to a talk that Hellman gave, he and Polig created a design for using modexp (using a prime modulus) to do symmetric crypto shortly before RSA; however it ended up being published afterwards (as RSA was seen as a breakthough, hence its publication was fasttracked...)

Comment: @poncho: I failed to locate a transcript of Hellman's talks (or even a recording/video). Any source?

Comment: Hmmmm, it was an invited talk at Crypto99; I wouldn't know if there are any recordings...

Comment: On second thought, it might have been Ralph Merkle's invited talk at Crypto05...